# Springboot : Show slow sql hibernate query properties not working as expected

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, application.properties

I am using the below properties in `application.properties` file

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=trace
spring.datasource.health.validation-query=SELECT 1
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL_SLOW=DEBUG
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.session.events.log.LOG_QUERIES_SLOWER_THAN_MS=5000
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration
```

and as expected i want to print the hibernate query which is taking more than 5second(`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.session.events.log.LOG_QUERIES_SLOWER_THAN_MS=5000`) to execute. But in the log, all queries are printing.
Example.

```
2023-09-26 18:24:10,136 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL                        | select lifecyclet0_.LIFECYCLE_TRANSITION_ID as lifecycl1_26_, lifecyclet0_.FROM_LIFECYCLE_STATE_ID as from_lif2_26_, lifecyclet0_.TO_LIFECYCLE_STATE_ID as to_lifec3_26_ from catmp6.LIFECYCLE_TRANSITIONS lifecyclet0_ where lifecyclet0_.FROM_LIFECYCLE_STATE_ID=?
2023-09-26 18:24:10,137 TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      | binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [4]
```

Can anyone suggest what is wrong here.

```
<spring.boot.version>2.7.2</spring.boot.version>
<psql.jdbc.version>42.5.1</psql.jdbc.version>
```

Comment: Which is what yuou told it to do by setting the `org.hibernate.SQL` log level to debug.

Comment: I tried `DEBUG/INFO` both not working.

Comment: As long as `org.hibernate.SQL` is lower or the same as the default log level it will log all queries. Just remove it (or set it to FATAL or something alike). The `show_sql=true` will also influence query logging.

Comment: Currently i made the changes `logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=FATAL` and `logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL_SLOW=INFO,
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.session.events.log.LOG_QUERIES_SLOWER_THAN_MS=500` but no any progress now no query printing while few query taking more time then 500MS.

Comment: Are the queries really taking more then 500ms or is it the whole process that is taking more than 500ms. Those are different things.

Comment: One query is taking more than 10min I want to print that query that's why I need this feature should work.

Comment: Is it **really the query** or the whole operation. Next to that what slow query means that it takes that long to get a response (so the query execution) if you get a response quickly but it takes 10 minutes to iterate trhough all the results that isn't a slow query.

Comment: No @Denum its query which is taking time ...Support i will add `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.session.events.log.LOG_QUERIES_SLOWER_THAN_MS=1` atleaset some other query it should print but nothing is printing 
`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=FATAL
pring.datasource.health.validation-query=SELECT 1
org.hibernate.SQL_SLOW=INFO 
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.session.events.log.LOG_QUERIES_SLOWER_THAN_MS=1`

Comment: Don't add additional code/config as comments as that is totally unreadable. I would suggest enabling hibernate statistics and export them, that will give you more information on slow queries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255437/discussion-between-subodh-joshi-and-m-deinum).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349344/how-to-monitor-slow-sql-queries-executed-by-jpa-and-hibernate as that explains what to do. Are you actually using that properties file? Are you using auto configuration for JPA or doing things yourself in that area?